# Which Bins are occupied in a 3D histogram in MatLab

Tags: matlab, 3d, histogram, unique

I got 3D data, from which I need to calculate properties.
To reduce computung I wanted to discretize the space and calculate the properties from the Bin instead of the individual data points and then reasign the propertie caclulated from the bin back to the datapoint.
I further only want to calculate the Bins which have points within them.
Since there is no 3D-binning function in MatLab, what i do is using histcounts over each dimension and then searching for the unique Bins that have been asigned to the data points.

```
a5pre=compositions(:,1);
a7pre=compositions(:,2);
a8pre=compositions(:,3);
%% BINNING

a5pre_edges=[0,linspace(0.005,0.995,19),1];
a5pre_val=(a5pre_edges(1:end-1) + a5pre_edges(2:end))/2;
a5pre_val(1)=0;
a5pre_val(end)=1;

a7pre_edges=[0,linspace(0.005,0.995,49),1];
a7pre_val=(a7pre_edges(1:end-1) + a7pre_edges(2:end))/2;
a7pre_val(1)=0;
a7pre_val(end)=1;

a8pre_edges=a7pre_edges;
a8pre_val=a7pre_val;

[~,~,bin1]=histcounts(a5pre,a5pre_edges); 
[~,~,bin2]=histcounts(a7pre,a7pre_edges); 
[~,~,bin3]=histcounts(a8pre,a8pre_edges); 

bins=[bin1,bin2,bin3];

[A,~,C]=unique(bins,'rows','stable');

a5pre=a5pre_val(A(:,1));
a7pre=a7pre_val(A(:,2));
a8pre=a8pre_val(A(:,3));
```

It seems like that the unique function is pretty time consuming, so I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it, knowing that the line only can contain integer or so... or a totaly different.

Best regards

Comment: It seems to me that you’re better off using the data as is, this binning procedure you’ve decided on seems painful. What structure does this 3D data have? Does it represent points on a single surface? What analysis are you doing on it? We might be able to help you come up with a better way to speed it up.

Comment: The data represent normalised chemical compositions. All variables are bewteen 0 and 1,  for the second and third variable there is the side conditions that they sum up to at least 0.9 but not more than 1.
With the compositions I calclate thermodynamic properties, the formula for those are multiple pages long....
I also liked to stay with the values itsself, since for smll number of compositions, the binning costs as much time as a save with the fewer calculations,,, for large numbers the binning is faster, but in reality i wont reach those large numbers.
But boss wants the binning...

Comment: So your binning is intended to compute those properties for a subset of compositions, representing approximations to all compositions in your data set? Have you tried writing your own histogram function? It’s quite simple, actually. It looks like MATLAB does have a 3D histogram, but it’s in the Statistics Toolbox: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html

Comment: Yeah, I calculate the properties of a subset, representing approximations to not all compositions, but the ones within this specific subset. 
Not every subset (Bin) will have data in it, so i just want to calculate the subset that contain data, and I want to calculate that subset just once and then asign the value to all data points within.
What would be the benefit of the 3D hist function, compared to my approach? From the "time and run", the unique funtion seems to be the bottle neck. 
Anyway the hist3 function is onl for 2D input, not 3D.

Comment: The hist3 function creates a 3D histogram, which is what you need. Your data is in a 2D array. Once you compute a 3D histogram, you don’t need the `unique` call. `find` will return the coordinates of bins that have samples in them. All you need to do is translate those bin indices back to coordinates in your system.

Comment: My data is a 3xN 2D array, but with X=(:,1), Y=(:,2) and Z=(:,3). from the documentary hist3 creates a bivariate histogram plot of X(:,1) and X(:,2), so one dimension too little, isnt it?

Comment: Oh, you’re right, what a stupid name for a 2D histogram function. Sorry, I should have looked at the page I linked to you. :( — Still, my suggestion stands, make an actual 3D histogram, which should be quite simple to implement yourself if you can’t find a ready-made implementation. It’s just that `unique` is a poor way of implementing it. Just create the 3D output array, loop over your data points, find the bin it falls into, and increment that bin.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [comps,C]=compo_binner(x,y,z,e1,e2,e3,v1,v2,v3)

C=NaN(length(x),1);
comps=NaN(length(x),3);
id=1;

for i=1:numel(x)
    B_temp(1,1)=v1(sum(x(i)>e1));
    B_temp(1,2)=v2(sum(y(i)>e2));
    B_temp(1,3)=v3(sum(z(i)>e3));

    C_id=sum(ismember(comps,B_temp),2)==3;
    if  sum(C_id)>0
        C(i)=find(C_id);
    else
        comps(id,:)=B_temp;
        id=id+1;
        C_id=sum(ismember(comps,B_temp),2)==3;
        C(i)=find(C_id>0);
    end

end

comps(any(isnan(comps), 2), :) = [];



end
```

But its way slower than the histcount, unique version. Cant avoid find-function, and thats a function you sure want to avoid in a loop when its about speed...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to compute a 3D histogram. If there's no built-in tool to compute one, it is simple to write one:

```matlab
function [H, lindices] = histogram3d(data, n)
% histogram3d   3D histogram
%    H = histogram3d(data, n) computes a 3D histogram from (x,y,z) values
%    in  the Nx3 array `data`. `n` is the number of bins between 0 and 1.
%    It is assumed all values in `data` are between 0 and 1.
assert(size(data,2) == 3, 'data must be Nx3');
H = zeros(n, n, n);
indices = floor(data * n) + 1;
indices(indices > n) = n;
lindices = sub2ind(size(H), indices(:,1), indices(:,2), indices(:,3));
for ii = 1:size(data,1)
   H(lindices(ii)) = H(lindices(ii)) + 1;
end
end
```

Now, given your `compositions` array, and binning each dimension into 20 bins, we get:

```matlab
[H, indices] = histogram3d(compositions, 20);
idx = find(H);
[x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(H), idx);
reduced_compositions = ([x,y,z] - 0.5) / 20;
```

The bin centers for `H` are at `((1:20)-0.5)/20`.

On my machine this runs in a fraction of a second for 5 million inputs points.

Now, for each `composition(ii,:)`, you have a number `indices(ii)`, which matches with another number `idx[jj]`, corresponding to `reduced_compositions(jj,:)`. One easy way to make the assignment of results is as follows:

```matlab
H(H > 0) = 1:numel(idx);
indices = H(indices);
```

Now for each `composition(ii,:)`, your closest match in the reduced set is `reduced_compositions(indices(ii),:)`.

Comment: Nice thanks, In reality the bins in the different directions are not the same.
Only thing missing for me is an array, that contains the information to reasign the reduced composition to the original data. Like C=[5 7 1 2...] means that the first datapoint has to be calculatet with the reduced_composition(5,:), second datapoint with reduced_composition(7,:). So i can calc only the reduced_compositionns ad the reasign the results calculated from those

Comment: @MarcLaub See edit. Do you now see how to get results from the reduced compositions assigned to the original compositions?

Comment: @Chris Luengo. Sry didnt have time to look at it till now. So I guess when I want to have different binning in each dimenion, its way less efficient? I know that the change in one variabe has less influence on the later results then other variables, so I would bin one in course bins and others in finer bins.

Comment: @MarcLaub No, using a different binning in each channel is trivial. The binning happens in the line `indices = floor(data * n) + 1;`. Instead of `*n` you can do `.*[n1,n2,n3]` to get a different binning for each dimension. Non-uniform binning (on an irregular grid)  is a bit more involved, but not necessarily much more expensive.

Comment: Yeah. It didnt work in the beginning because I havent seen you also editet your entire function. Just have to fix the the values asigned to the bins. the outerbins ahould be very narrow and the value asigned to the bin should be 0 and 1, and not the mean of the adjacend edges

Comment: @MarcLaub If you need non-uniform binning, try [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.discretize.html) instead of `floor(data*n)`.

Comment: I implemented all. So for a set of 40k points, your approach improvs the binning by about 30%, from 0.003s to about 0.002 seconds compar to the approach in my question. 
But somehow, even though I just change the binning function, rest remains the same, the overall evaluation (calc the properties with the reduced compositons and reassign them)... decelerates from about 0.004s to 0.005s, not sure why yet...
Thanks anyway very much

Comment: @MarcLaub Those are all tiny times, hard to time consistently. Use `timeit` to time these functions, and make sure to close all other programs on your system, as any outside activity will affect the timing.

Comment: its the mean value from 10000 iterations. So with my approach the overall time for 10k iterations take like 41s and with your approach 46s